# How to show a grid in an view using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, gridview

I am getting grid in the view, but the line goes beyond the frame  I have attached the image which I got as an output  How to fix this issue

[image]

```
    path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 5.0

    for index in 1...Int(gridWidthMultiple) - 1
    {
        let start = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * gridWidth, y: 0)
        let end = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * gridWidth, y: bounds.height)
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
    }
    let numberOfRows: Int = Int(self.frame.size.height)/Int(gridWidth);

    for index in 1...numberOfRows {
        let start = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: gridWidth * CGFloat(index))
        let end = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: start.y)
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
    }
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: What's your view hierarchy like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to set the clipsToBounds property of the grid view to true?